# Proper design of common repository and context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a `UserEntity`. This user can have a collection of `ImageEntity` as gallery.
Thus, a `UserRepository` and `UserContext` are made for `UserEntity` and `ImageRepository` and `ImageContext` are made for `ImageEntity`.
When adding an Image to a User's gallery, the code-behind in the `UserRepository` is adding the image using the `ImageRepository` to the database (with the user's GUID) and then simply adding it to its collection.

The models:

```
public class ImageEntity : IEntityBase
{
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
    public bool isActive { get; set; } = true;
    public string FullPath { get; set; } = "";
    public Guid RelatedTo { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
}

public class UserEntity: IEntityBase, IFileRelatableEntity
{
    ...
    public ICollection<ImageEntity> RelatedFiles { get; } = new List<ImageEntity>();
}
```

The repo of User:

```
public void AddRelatedFiles<T>(Guid p_guid, IEnumerable<IFormFile> p_files) where T : class, IEntityBase, IFileRelatableEntity
    {
        UserEntity user = GetSpecific<UserEntity>(p_guid);
        string relatedWorkAppId = GetSpecific<UserEntity>(user.AssignedToWork).ApplicativeId;
        foreach (var file in p_files)
        {
            // Add using the ImageRepo
            ImageEntity relatedFile = m_fileRepository.AddRelatedFile(p_guid, "Users\\" + relatedWorkAppId, file);
            // Add to the entity
            user.RelatedFiles.Add(relatedFile);
        }
    }
```

**Problem:**
This resulted another creation of SQL Table named `ImageEntity` only for the images related to `UserEntity`.

1. This is redundant
2. Not scalable, since adding another entity (like `JobEntity`) will result creation of another table.

**How do I enforce?:**

1. `relatedTo` in the `ImageEntity` to be FK?
2. Not creating a special table, but `.Include`ing using the main table of `ImageEntity`?

Maybe you have other suggestions?